# "Through all things, kindness"

Tags: translation-check, sentence-translation

I'm looking to translate a sentence, and need conjugation help.

The motto would be "through all things/trials/struggles, (loving) kindness."

So far I have:

> Per conatio omina, bonitatis...

Is this translation fine so far? How do I finish the sentence?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I made some edits to your question, but feel free to edit it further or undo the edits if you want to. I warmly recommend taking a look at our [tour] and registering your account, so that you get better access to your question, including editing, commenting, and voting on answers.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind using Christian vocabulary, your quote is an almost exact translation of St Augustine's famous saying:

> *In necessariis unitas, in dubiis libertas, **in omnibus caritas.***

This is:

> In necessary things, unity. In uncertain things, liberty. **In all things, charity.**

Comment: Can you explain how well *caritas* corresponds to (loving) kindness? I think it's a good fit, but elaborating on it might be useful for the OP.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta charity is definitely associated with Agape: "love; the highest form of love, charity" LSJ: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)ga%2Fph, Middle Liddell: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Da)ga%2Fph

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It's such a good fit the Church frequently translates *caritas* as 'lovingkindness' rather than charity when creating English texts.  It would be hard to do better.

Comment: @brianpck I see what you mean by invoking Augustine : as a whole, it captures the intention nicely and, in spite of the several meanings which can be given to _caritas_ according to context, I certainly wouldn't argue against that. But do you suggest using only the three emphasised words? That would surely be to ignore the questioner's 'trials/struggles' — or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

Your first effort indicates that you are starting without much knowledge of Latin so, rather than explain what's not right about it, can I make a couple of suggestions?

For a motto, a verb can often (as you have done here) be omitted. You might like :

*rebus in arduis benignitas*, kindliness when things are difficult ;

— alternatively, *per rebus adversis cum benignitate,* with kindliness through adversity.

There are many other possibilities. Perhaps you could make the context a little fuller?